# how to reuse same set of validations on different columns and different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

We have same set of validations on different fields.
we have fee columns. with the following validations

```
validates :sytem_fee, presence: true, 
                      format: { with: fee_regex, message: format_error_message }, 
                      numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 40 }
validates :sytem_discounted_fee, presence: true, 
                                 format: { with: fee_regex, message: format_error_message }, 
                                 numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 40 }
```

The set of validations applied to the columns is basically the same.
we have also the fees in different models. They have the same validations basicaly.
I know that there are custom validators like: `EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator`

My question is: can we create a custom validator that uses the default validations like presence, numericallity and so on?

The idea is to be able to say `validates some_fee, percent_fee_column: true`in any model

Answer (score 0):

You can put your method in the app/models/concerns folder, for example, as Validatable module (i.e. validatable.rb):

```
module Concerns::Validatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def format_website
    if website.blank?
      self.website = nil
    elsif !self.website[/^https?/]
      self.website = "http://#{self.website}"
    end
  end

end
```

And then include it in each models as

```
include Concerns::Validatable
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of using a concnern to do validations. Also a better approach would be to do  something like : `module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.validates_fee(*fees, options = {  })
      fees.each do |fee|
        validates presence: true, format: { with: percent_regex, message: err_msg}, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: optiosn[fee] || 60 }  
      end
    end
  end
end

class SomeClass < ActiveRecord
  validates_fee :custom_fee, {custom_fee: 40 } 
end`

Comment: @k0k0 So I wanted to come in here and respond to this comment, because I think concerns are a correct place to put reused validations. The Rails guides on "getting started" specifically call out reused validations as a reason to use concerns: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#validations-and-displaying-error-messages. You didn't give your reasons for "not liking" putting validations in concerns, but it appears to be a valid use case.